# Table of contents points to wrong page for sections, not for subsection

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I am using latex for a big report, using the article class. So far, so good.

The problems is the table of contents does not point to the right page for sections. It works great for subsections (as far as I can tell, there are too many to try them all). I looked a bit online so I tried

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of contents}
```

But that did not help much.

This is what I have:

```
\clearpage\phantomsection
\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
\pagenumbering{roman}%

\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of contents}
\tableofcontents


\newpage{}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\listoffigures


\newpage{}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\listoftables
```

I also tried this:

```
% Try and fix wrong clicking
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

But that did not help either.

This is how my sections are defined:

```
 % custom section
 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \usepackage{tipa}
 \titleformat{\section}
 {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
 {\thesection\hskip 10pt\textpipe\hskip 10pt}
 {0pt}
 {}
 % Continue on a new page after a section has finished
 \newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
```

Apart from this, I do not use anything special. Any ideas?

```
    % Try and fix wrong clicking
    \documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}
    \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

    \usepackage{hyperref}
     % custom section

     \usepackage{titlesec}
     \usepackage{tipa}
     \titleformat{\section}
     {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
     {\thesection\hskip 10pt\textpipe\hskip 10pt}
     {0pt}
     {}
     % Continue on a new page after a section has finished
     \newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}

    \begin{document}

    \clearpage\phantomsection
    \pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
    \pagenumbering{roman}%

    \hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of contents}
    \tableofcontents


    \newpage{}
    \hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
    \cleardoublepage\phantomsection
    \listoffigures


    \newpage{}
    \hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
    \cleardoublepage\phantomsection
    \listoftables


    \section{Introduction}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
    \pagenumbering{arabic}


    \end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Unrelated: Why are there multiple (and identical) `\hypersetup` - commands?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer updated the question with a MWE.

Comment: Open minded to use scrartcl (the article class of KOMA script). That would make things much easier for you.

Comment: @Johannes_B: `titlesec` and KOMA-classes collide somehow -- during a compilation run there normally is some warning by the KOMA script that `titlesec` should not be used in conjunction with KOMA

Comment: @elaRosca: Is that `|` (`\textpipe`) character in your titlesec actually wanted?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer If you decide to go with a KOMA class, you don't need things like `titletoc`, `titlesec` or `tocbibind`.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I don't need the packages you mentioned ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There should be at least a `\clearpage` or a `\cleardoublepage` command directly after `listoftables`, since it is empty at the moment, so that there is no need to shipout a new page and the `\section{Introduction}` starts on that page, which is probably not intended if one does not want to save paper ;-)

As the section appears on the wrong page, the implied hypertarget for this section header is placed on the wrong page as well, regardless, whether `titlesec` is used or not.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{hyperref}
 % custom section


\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tipa}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
{\thesection\hskip 10pt\textpipe\hskip 10pt}
{0pt}
{}
% Continue on a new page after a section has finished
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}

\begin{document}

\clearpage\phantomsection
\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)

\pagenumbering{roman}%

\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of contents}
\tableofcontents


\newpage{}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\listoffigures

\newpage{}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage %%% Added here!!!!

\section{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
\pagenumbering{arabic}


\end{document}
```

**Edit** Other version without `titlesec` in order to keep the `|` style in section header

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}%
\usepackage{blindtext} %Can be removed later on
\usepackage{forloop}   %Can be removed later on

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{etoolbox}%

\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=3,bookmarksnumbered=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}%

\newrobustcmd{\toggle}[1]{%
\iftoggle{#1}{\togglefalse{#1}}{\toggletrue{#1}}%
}%

\newtoggle{SectionAutoClearpage}%
\settoggle{SectionAutoClearpage}{true}%

\usepackage{tipa}

\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{%
\iftoggle{SectionAutoClearpage}{%
\clearpage%
}{%
% No, then do nothing here
}% End of \iftoggle
}% End of \sectionbreak%

\let\LaTeXStandardTheSection\thesection%

\let\LaTeXStandardSection\section

\newrobustcmd{\MySectionHeaderFormat}{\textpipe\hskip 10pt}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\unstarredsection@opt}[2][]{%
\sectionbreak%
\LaTeXStandardSection[#1]{\MySectionHeaderFormat #1}%
}%

\newcommand{\unstarredsection@noopt}[1]{%
\unstarredsection[#1]{#1}%
}%


\newcommand{\starredsection}[1]{%
\LaTeXStandardSection*{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\unstarredsection}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\unstarredsection@opt}{\unstarredsection@noopt}%
}%

\renewcommand{\section}{%
\@ifstar{\starredsection}{\unstarredsection}%
}%



\makeatother

\begin{document}

\clearpage\phantomsection
\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)

\pagenumbering{roman}%

\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\phantomsection%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of contents}
\tableofcontents


%\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\listoffigures

%\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\listoftables

%\togglefalse{SectionAutoClearpage} Disable it, just for fun%
\section{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\blindtext

% Generate some dummy sections, just to show that the links work
%%% Anything after this can be removed, except \end{document} of course ;-)

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}


%\togglefalse{SectionAutoClearpage}%

\newcounter{seccounter}
\forloop{seccounter}{2}{\number\value{seccounter} < 21}{%
\toggle{SectionAutoClearpage}%
\section{Section Number \Roman{seccounter}}%
\blindtext

\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=4cm]{some_fig}%
\captionof{figure}{Dummy Figure number \Roman{seccounter}}
}%

\end{document}
```

Explanation: This solution is the hard way, without using the possibilities of the KOMA classes

The redefined section commands explicitly use a `section name prefix` 
defined in `\MySectionHeaderFormat` in the unstarred `\section` commands, however, it is prevented that this format is used in the TOC also.
`\MySectionHeaderFormat` is defined to be `\textpipe\hskip 10pt`, but can be changed to anything else being allowed in a section header too.

As soon as `\section` is redefined, `\tableofcontents` complains, since it gets inconsistent with the `\section*` command used by `\tableofcontents`, it is just sufficient to force `\section*{}` back to the old `\LaTeXStandardSection*` command, but has to be explicitly stated, the alternative would be to redefine `\tableofcontents` itself.

I introduced a boolean toggle flag `SectionAutoClearpage` which is initially set to true, such that there is clearpage before the new section begins, just say `\togglefalse{SectionAutoClearpage}` to switch this feature off at any place where appropiate.

The last part of the document just write some dummy sections in order to show the effect of the new section commands.

[image]

Comment: The real problem does not have an empty list, and this still occurs.

Comment: The interesting thing to notice is that even though the list of figures and list of tables have multiple pages, it still points right to them. The problem starts since the introduction.

Comment: The problem is just that weird `titlesec` package. It does not set the links correctly

Comment: You are right, that is it. Do you know how I can achieve a pipe on the left hand side of a section with something else? like sectsty?

Comment: @elaRosca: I dropped `titlesec` and `sectsty` completely, it uses no other formatting package and I posted a new version