# Equivalent of titlesec with sectsty

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I am using

```
 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \usepackage{tipa}
 \titleformat{\section}
 {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
 {\thesection\hskip 10pt\textpipe\hskip 10pt} 
 {0pt}
 {}
```

for formatting my sections. The only problem is that it has issues with `hyperref` and I cannot link the sections nicely.

See here [Table of contents points to wrong page for sections, not for subsection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184708/table-of-contents-points-to-wrong-page-for-sections-not-for-subsection) for the original problem and a MWE.

I just want the same formatting (a pipe before the section name) with another package (`sectsty` or others). Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need no package for this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \csname the#1\endcsname % the number
  \hspace{10pt}$|$\hspace{10pt}% space, bar, space
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Here's the section title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This will add the vertical bar also in subsection titles, but it's possible to limit it just to sections.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  % the number
  \csname the#1\endcsname
  % the formatting for the current level
  \@ifundefined{format#1}{\quad}{\csname format#1\endcsname}
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\formatsection}{%
  \hspace{10pt}$|$\hspace{10pt}% space, bar, space
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Here's the section title}

\subsection{Here's a subsection}

\end{document}
```

If you don't define `\format<level>`, the usual `\quad` will be added between the number and the title.

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me on how to limit it to the sections?

Comment: Is it possible for me to also make the section names bigger?

Comment: @elaRosca I added the code for having the pipe only in sections. For making the font larger, use `sectsty`. But avoid it, the font size is already quite large.

Comment: Thank you. The issue is that now it does not start a new page when a new section starts.I am using `\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}` for doing that.

Comment: @elaRosca Defining `\sectionbreak` will do nothing; do `\usepackage{etoolbox}` and `\preto{\section}{\clearpage}` if you really want to start a new page with each section. But judging from the context, you seem to be wanting the `report` class and use `\chapter` instead of `\section`.